# Mysql вывод данных PHP

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет !
столкнулся с такой проблемой когда я хочу вывести что то из бд
на Over flow мне предлагают вывести все с помощью цмклов
можно ли как то сделать что то типо `$id = SELECT * FROM "БАЗА" "НАПРИМЕР ТАБЛИЦА ID"` и потом вывести `echo = $id;` не мучится с этими циклами итд, зарание спасибо !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если строка одна - можно без циклов, цикл нужен для перебора нескольких строк.
Я приведу оба примера.

Если строка одна:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("ХОСТ", "ЛОГИН", "ПАРОЛЬ", "БД", "ПОРТ"); //ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ К БД

$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table"); //ЗАПРОС К БД
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); // Получаем строку в массив
echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); //Выводим из массива значение по названию столбца
```

А вот если строк несколько, мы будем по очереди разбирать каждую строку, и выводить:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("ХОСТ", "ЛОГИН", "ПАРОЛЬ", "БД", "ПОРТ"); //ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ К БД

$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table"); //ЗАПРОС К БД

// В $row возвращаются строки по очереди
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); // Выводим значение по названию столбца

} //Этот цикл выполняется столько раз, сколько строк в таблице
```

Важно помнить, что при выводе любых данных в HTML, их необходимо соответствующим образом форматировать, с помощью функции `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @Maxproger добавил комментарии к каждой строчке. $row это переменная, куда в нашем случае записывается массив столбцов строки, и соответственно из неё можно получить значение столбца по его названию.

Comment: спасибо, как еще один rep поставить)

Comment: @Maxproger к комментарию разве что :)) Удачи в обучении, циклы поначалу не самая простая тема, но достаточно будет несколько программ написать с их использованием, и будет всё ясно как белый день 

Comment: не циклы то я изучил, просто мне надо было вывести одну таблицу

Comment: @Maxproger ну вот по аналогии с `$row['id']` пишешь рядом названия столбцов других (например `$row['name']`, `$row['phone']` и выводишь их в одну строчку, а после вывода *(внутри цикла)* `echo '<br>';` например, и каждый цикл будет выводить с новой строки каждую строчку...)